# How to filter websites per ip address with privoxy?

Tags: proxy, web, filtering, acl

I installed privoxy on Ubuntu server 14.04 and I am stack in filtering websites per IP address. I read the manual and I came across the section about ACLs: permit-access and deny-access. 
My subnet is 192.168.2.0/24
I tried this:
deny-access   192.168.2.61   www.youtube.com

But it did not work.
Anyone knows how to resolve this ?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Privoxy's ACLs honor a "last match wins" rule. So you may tweak the order of your ACLs in the config file by placing deny-access **after** permit-access.